# Python logging module returning errors for no reason

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to learn to use the logging module, but I keep getting similar error messages when I actually try to log a message with a Logger object.  I can't make sense of the error message either.  What am I doing wrong?  This is all in IDLE, by the way.

```
>>> import logging
>>> import sys
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("name")
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
>>> h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.addHandler(h)
>>> h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s|%(level)s|%(message)s"))
>>> logger.debug("hey")
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 622, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 591, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 433, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'level'
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 144, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'hey'
Arguments: ()
```

Comment: according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) it shoud be `%(levelname)s` i guess. (python usually doesn't raise exceptions 'for no reason').

Comment: Holy moly thank you so much!  I can't believe it was that simple of an error.

Comment: not a problem! happy pythoning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the LogRecord attributes described in [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) (also see this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages)):

```
levelname    %(levelname)s    Text logging level for the message ('DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL').
```

The problem is at `h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s|%(level)s|%(message)s"))` (as pointed out in your traceback **(KeyError: 'level')**).

Your should be using `%(levelname)s`. For example:

```
h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now can you tell me why my SMTPHandler isn't working?  I created a SMTPHandler like so: `mail_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler('smtp.gmail.com', "my_email@gmail.com","my_email@gmail.com", 'The server died. That sucks... :(',credentials=("my_email@gmail.com", "my_password"))` and added it to a logger.  When I logged with the info method, I got a huge error.

Comment: You need to post another question for that.

Comment: How do I mark it as closed?

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, then accept the answer by clicking on right tick on left of this answer.

Comment: Thank you! Time to make a new question :p